# По какому принципу работают (int) и intval?

Tags: php

В документации указано, что максимальное знаковое целое число для функции `9223372036854775807`.

И, если мы в функцию добавляем строку с превышенной нормой, то на выходе получим `9223372036854775807`.

```
echo (int) '4200000000000000000000';
// 9223372036854775807
```

Но если будет не строка, а число - на выходе получаем нечто, по не ясным принципам:

```
echo (int) 4200000000000000000000;
// -5857648805777768448
```

Почему так?

Comment: Потому что переполнение?

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему при касте строки получаем PHP_INT_MAX, а не переполнение..

Comment: @vp_arth это у вас такой вопрос, а у автора про переполнение :)

Comment: меня интересует именно повдеение функции, почему если задаем стрингу, то возвращает максимальное значение. А когда задаем число, то на выходе получаем непонятное число, полученное по непонятным алгоритмам )

Comment: но вообще да, интересно почему int_max получается при касте строки. при неявном приведении по правилам получается соответствующий float.

Comment: @Katanji, оффтоп-совет - исключите "стрингу" из лексикона. Используйте "строку".

Comment: спасибо, принял

Comment: вообще возврат INT_MAX для `intval` документирован. прочитал по диагонали

Comment: то-есть если пускаем строку, то оно сверяет максимальное значение для (int) со строкой и если превышение, то возвращает 9223372036854775807, а если запускаем число с превышением, то возвращает INT_MAX ?

Answer (score 2):

Переполнение сетки же. Оно у вас несколько раз происходит.

Для теста можете такой код запустить:

```
$test = 4200000000000000000000 - 9223372036854775807;
while($test > 0) {
    $test = $test - 9223372036854775807;
}

echo (int)$test; // -5857648805777768448
```

Comment: но почему когда задаем стрингу, нет переполнения сетки?
echo (int) '4200000000000000000000';
// 9223372036854775807   - то максимальное значение, которое указано в документации

Comment: интересно, что если мы в этой формуле будет изменять 4200000000000000000000 на 4200000000000000000001, 4200000000000000000002 и так далее, то результат все-равно остается неизменным // -5857648805777768448